# What requirements are necessary for a webhoster to host Diaspora*?

Tags: web-hosting, social-media

What do I need to get from a webhoster if I want to host my own [Diaspora*](http://www.joindiaspora.com/) seed? Do I just need some webspace with ruby on rails capabilities?

Comment: https://twitter.com/warrenmyers/status/452797591059562496

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installation requirements from the [Github page](http://github.com/diaspora/diaspora):

> In order to run Diaspora, you will
>   need to download the following
>   dependencies (specific instructions
>   follow):
>
> - Build Tools - Packages needed to compile the components that follow.
> - Ruby - The Ruby programming language. (We're using 1.8.7. It comes preinstalled on Mac OS X.)
> - MongoDB - A snappy noSQL database.
> - OpenSSL - An encryption library. (It comes preinstalled on Mac OS X and Ubuntu.)
> - ImageMagick - An Image processing library used to resize uploaded photos.
> - Git - The fast version control system.
>
> After you have Ruby installed on your
>   system, you will need to get RubyGems,
>   then install Bundler:
>
> - RubyGems - Source for Ruby gems.
> - Bundler - Gem management tool for Ruby projects.

That is realistically beyond what your typical webhost will offer. (Git and even Ruby are non-standard for many webhosts. MongoDB? Get outta here...)

You might be better off with a VPS.

Comment: Ouch! So the entrance barrier is pretty high. Nothing the average computer enthusiast would be able to handle himself. He actually does depend on the support of the hoster.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I cannot answer your question directly, but one thing you need to consider is the security flaws this **pre-alpha** release of Diaspora* has:

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/09/16/diaspora_pre_alpha_landmines/

Comment: -1 I am aware of this (it is pre Alpha after all) and it is not what I was asking. I just wanted to get an idea of what approximate costs and maintaince efforts we are talking here, when hosting a seed.